# adding to a list defined in a function

Tags: python, list, function, append

How can I create a list in a function, append to it, and then pass another value into the function to append to the list.

For example:

```
def another_function():
    y = 1
    list_initial(y)

def list_initial(x):
    list_new = [ ]
    list_new.append(x)
    print list_initial

another_function()
list_initial(2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  The code you have will work just fine, but I don't understand what `another_function` has to do with `list_initial`.  Is there something about this code that isn't what you want?

Comment: My mistake.  I fixed another_function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you're after something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def make_list(first_item):
    list_new = []
    list_new.append(first_item)
    return list_new

def add_item(list, item):
    list.append(item)
    return list

mylist = make_list(1)
mylist = add_item(mylist, 2)

print mylist    # prints [1, 2]
```

Or even:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def add_item(list, item):
    list.append(item)
    return list

mylist = []
mylist = add_item(mylist, 1)
mylist = add_item(mylist, 2)

print mylist    # prints [1, 2]
```

But, this kind of operation isn't usually worth wrapping with functions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#
# Does the same thing
#
mylist = []
mylist.append(1)
mylist.append(2)

print mylist    # prints [1, 2]
```

Comment: `list.append()` modifies the list, so you don't need to return list from `add_item` .. and your `make_list` function can just `return [ first_item ]` in one line, instead of three.

Comment: True, but I was trying not to deviate too far from the OP's original code.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a list that is scoped to your function, you can do this:

```
def list_at_function_scope(arg,lst=[]):
    lst.append(arg)
    return lst

print list_at_function_scope(2)
print list_at_function_scope("qwqwe")
```

And it looks like this:

```
>>> print list_at_function_scope(2)
[2]
>>> print list_at_function_scope("qwqwe")
[2, 'qwqwe']
```

Mind you, this is generally regarded as a well-known anti-pattern/error in python. Just so you know what you are getting yourself into.

Comment: Thanks!  Any suggestions for doing this in a more python like way?

Comment: "python like way", otherwise known as being "pythonic" is *very* often misunderstood. Most examples of so called "pythonic" code that i've seen are quite the opposite of the developer's own definition (paraphrased): "to be clear and concise", which this is.

Comment: can you tell me why is this happening ? where can i read more about it ?